# adding four lines before last line of the file in gvim

Tags: vim

IS there a way to add 4 lines before the last line of the file in vim?

I'm new to vim and recently found out that vim does multiline search which is awesome.  Now only if I could find how to add 4 lines before the last line in the file I would totally save immense amount of time

Comment: What does that multi-line search have to do with your question?

Comment: Where does the lines you want to add come from? If it's from another (template) file, or from some computations, `$-1put=lines_list`would do the trick. If you plan to enter them interactively, `GO` is a good option.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

`G` jumps to the end of the file. Then press `O` to insert a line before that last line. Now hit `Enter` three times and you have four lines before the last line.